# Can you copy a member of an object that's passed by reference?

Tags: c++

Consider below code,

```
void handleConnection(Connection &connection) {
    // std::vector
    auto messages = connection->messages;

    // Do Work

    
    messages.clear();
}
```

Why does assigning `connection->messages` to `auto messages` creates a copy without implicitly creating a reference?

The main reason I asked this question is because I noted the above code causing duplicate messages and that means it makes a copy, but I cannot find a law in the C ++ standard that describes this.

Comment: Yes, it makes a copy.

Comment: C++ has value semantics for all types, including for pointers themselves, customizable by `operator=`. If you want a reference, use one. If you need a pointer, use one too

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `auto&` is const? I see no point using `auto&&` here.

Comment: @jeffbRTC I didn't sugggest using it. It was a reply to a now-deleted comment, that incorrectly explained `&` vs `&&` references. I've deleted it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) state that the following code:

```
auto x = y;
```

will *always* make a copy of `y`, and deduce the type of `x` to be the same as `y`. Whether `y` is a member of an object that you're holding a reference to, is completely irrelevant.

Similarly,

```
auto &x = y;
```

will make `x` a reference to `y`, with the same type. Whether `y` is a member of an object of which you have a copy or a reference, doesn't affect this at all.